# Which episode is the one where the cat from the eye of thundera gets out of the sword?

Tags: episode-identification, thundercats

I remember in the original Thundercats series there was an episode where the cat from the eye of thundera gets out from the sword and fights some evil or something. But it was many years ago and I can't remember which episode was. Having Thundercats 130 episodes or something, it's hard to find. Which episode it was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I founded it, it's in episode 88th Runaways. It appears at the end of the episode

[image]